# HTML5 Geo Location pass Lat and Lon to PHP page

Tags: html, geolocation

I have a small piece of code which i want to collect the lat and lon co ordinates and then passes them to a php page.

However the code doesn't seem to be passing the variables to the php page.

Below is the code, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
  if(navigator.geolocation)
  {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
   {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   document.location = "test1.php?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + 
                   longitude;

    });
 }
```

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a simple variable name mismatch. You define `lat` and `lon` but use `latitude` and `longitude` on the next line. Try changing them to be the same pair.

Comment: Thank you, how did i miss that?, much appreciated